# Array multisort numbers in increasing order

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, array-multisort

Is the following code acceptable for sorting the data within array by commentID in increasing order?

I cannot test the code right now because I have no test values in my database.

```
$comments = array();

---insert mysql data into $comments here---

$tmp = Array();
foreach($comments as &$ma)
$tmp[] = &$ma["commentID"];
array_multisort($tmp, $comments);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it the following way:

```
$comments = array();
// Use your preferred mysql driver here
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $comments[$row["id"]] = $row["comment"];
}
$success = ksort($comments);
```

`ksort` will sort the array from lowest to highest based on keys.  In this instance the key is the id from the database.  Let me know if this is unclear, or if this isn't what you want.

Comment: where does the $success variable come from?

Comment: ksort returns true or false based on whether the sorting succeeds.  I just set it to $success so you can capture that result to check to see if it succeeded.

Comment: alright and this will only work if i set commentID as a KEY in my database, correct?

Comment: No, that isn't necessary (though you probably want to).  You can access any column in the table using row["<column name>"].  You could run into trouble if there are multiple rows in the table with the same ID because the values would get over written in the while loop.  So in that sense the id should be a unique key (probably the primary key).